# How can I start a new process without exiting the previous process in C# using process.start

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, process.start, simultaneous

When I say open wordpad, wordpad opens. After that when I say open notepad. wordpad closes and notepad opens.

I want both wordpad and notepad to be open.

```
//This function is called on recognising my voice.
private void SRE_SpeechRecognised(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Result.Text.ToString())
    {
        case "wordpad"
        {
                Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\wordpad\wordpad.exe");
                break;
        }
        case "notepad"
        {
                Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\notepad\notepad.exe");
                break;
        }
        case "word"
        {
                Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\word\word.exe");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) don't use a `switch` statement if you want all started at once, 2) check your paths - on my system at least wordpad and notepad are not in `c:\Program Files`.

Comment: `Process.Start` shouldn't be closing anything either. If they are closing before you're closing them yourself, it's not this code doing it. I also wouldn't expect any of these exes to exist in just the root of `C:\Program Files`. Normally if they're in that folder somewhere, they'll be in a more specific subfolder (for example, my notepad.exe is located at `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`).

Comment: @steve Can you please reopen this task as I am still looking for answers.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I have updated the code to as it is in my device. When I start one process the other closes.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't compile. You'll need to put together a [mcve].

Comment: Apart from the syntax error (your case statements are missing the ":"), this code works properly. There is something else going on if Notepad/Wordpad etc are closing, but it isn't this code. I made a small sample of my machine to confirm this, and so far as I can see, it is working as intended.